# Empty array in an object is not being passed a value in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, object, inheritance, pdo

Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function DataObject::__construct(), 0 passed in C:\wamp64\www\phpscripts\bookclub\viewmember.php on line 7 and exactly 1 expected in C:\wamp64\www\phpscripts\bookclub\DataObject.class.php on line 5

Here is my DataObject.class.php file where the exception is raised. I am passing values to this array from the Member.class.php file below, but i keep getting the error shown above. I've been stuck on this for a few weeks now. I tried setting the array to null but that didn't do anything. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

DataObject.class.php:

```
<?php
require_once( "config.php");
abstract class DataObject {
protected $data = [null];
public function __construct($data) {
    if (isset($data)) {
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            if (array_key_exists($key, $this->data)) $this->data[$key] = $value;
        }
    } else {
        echo "array is empty!";
    }
    
}
public function getValue($field) {
    if (array_key_exists($field, $this->data)) {
        return $this->data[$field];
    } else {
        die("Field not found!");
    }
}
public function getValueEncoded($field) {
    return htmlspecialchars($this->getValue($field));
}
protected function connect() {
    try {
        $conn = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT, true);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage() );
    }
    return $conn;
}
protected function disconnect($conn) {
    $conn = "";
}
}
?>
```

Member.class.php:

```
<?php
require_once "DataObject.class.php";
class Member extends DataObject {
protected $data = array(
    "id" => "",
    "username" => "",
    "password" => "",
    "firstName" => "",
    "lastName" => "",
    "joinDate" => "",
    "gender" => "",
    "favoriteGenre" => "",
    "emailAddress" => "",
    "otherInterests" => ""
);
private $_genres = array(
    "crime" => "Crime",
    "horror" => "Horror",
    "thriller" => "Thriller",
    "romance" => "Romance",
    "sciFi" => "Sci-Fi",
    "adventure" => "Adventure",
    "nonFiction" => "Non-Fiction"
);
public function getMembers($startRow, $numRows, $order) {
    $conn = new DataObject();
    $conn->connect();
    
    $sql = "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM " . TBL_MEMBERS . "ORDER BY $order LIMIT :startRow, :numRows";
    try{
        $st = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $st->bindValue(":startRow", $startRow, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $st->bindValue(":numRows", $numRows, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $st->execute();
        $members = array();
        foreach ($st->fetchAll() as $row) {
            $members[] = new Member($row);
        }
        $st = $conn->query( "SELECT found_rows() AS totalRows" );
        $row = $st->fetch();
        $conn->disconnect();
        return array($members, $row["totalRows"]);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        $conn->disconnect();
        die("Query failed: " . $e->getMessage());
    }
}
public static function getMember($id) {
    $conn =(new DataObject())->connect();
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM " . TBL_MEMBERS . " WHERE id = :id";
    try {
        $st = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $st->bindValue(":id", $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $st->execute();
        $row = $st->fetch();
        $conn->disconnect;
        if ($row) return new Member($row);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        $conn->disconnect;
        die("Query failed: " . $e->getMessage() );
    }
}
public function getGenderString() {
    return ($this->data["gender"] == "f") ? "Female" : "Male";
}
public function getFavoriteGenreString() {
    return ($this->_genres[$this->data["favoriteGenre"]]);
}
}
?>
```

Comment: You are not, in fact, "passing values to this array from the Member.class.php file". There are two places where you're calling `new DataObject()`, but the constructor for `DataObject` requires one argument, `$data`. If you want to be able to pass nothing in, and have it generate your error message in that case, then define the constructor as `public function __construct($data = [])`.

Comment: I also have to ask what you're trying to accomplish by having your `Member` class extend `DataObject`, but then also creating new instances of the `DataObject` class inside the `Member` functions. It seems you may not have a strong grasp on how object inheritance works, and would be well served by doing some reading on that topic.

Comment: After getting this to work, please, post it on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ - there is so much wrong in this code and I hope at least some issues could be fixed

Answer (score 0):

You say you are passing values to the array required by DataObject from the Member.class.php file. However, it doesn't look like you are passing anything into DataObject when you create it. The exception is being thrown because you call `DataObject` without any parameters.

```
//When you call this, you need to pass in a parameter to the constructor
$conn = new DataObject(); 
// Like this instead
$conn = new DataObject($array);
```

You are defining Member to *extend* DataObject. That doesn't give DataObject anything. It makes Member a subclass of DataObject. So `Member` inherits the properties and functions of DataObject. Then if you want to add functionality to `Member` you can.

From your code here it looks like you may benefit from reading up on OOP (Object Oriented Programing) principles.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/reflection.extending.php
https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php

I can't think of an occasion where you would create a new instance of a super class (DataObject) inside of a sub class (Member).

I'm going to go out on a limb and guess that you did not intend to create a `new DataObject` inside Member. You are simply trying to use the `connect` function. You originally extended DataObject so that Member could take advantage of some of DataObjects ability. If that is what you are looking to do, you should be able to try this:

```
. . .
public function getMembers($startRow, $numRows, $order) {
    $conn = $this->connect(); //Member has the connect function because it inherited it
    $sql = "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM " . TBL_MEMBERS . "ORDER BY $order LIMIT :startRow, :numRows"; 
. . .
public static function getMember($id) {
    $conn = $this->connect(); //connect inherited when you extended DataObject
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM " . TBL_MEMBERS . " WHERE id = :id";
. . .
```

Then at some point in your code you are going to call `$member = new Member();`. You are going to have a similar challenge. Since Member inherits the `__construct()` function from DataObject, it is going to expect an array as input. So you will need to make sure at that point you call new Member with the right parameter `$member = new Member($dataArray);`

Please add more explanation if this is not what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Honestly this was a code example based on php 5 that was in a book that I was reading for class. I thought I could get it to work but some of the code they had made was deprecated so I was trying to update the code to php 8 standards.